# How can i see active threads over time from jtl file

Tags: jmeter

When i am executing my test in non-gui mode and trying to see active threads over time from jtl file.It does not show any data.I tried to make changes in properties file but no result.

Answer (score 2):

What version of JMeter you are using? From 2.11 JMeter shows the result in the summariser mode in the console output. You can see the number of active threads while it is running in non gui mode.

You can use this listener to load the jtl file to see the active threads over time.

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/

Answer (score 0):

Set "jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts" to TRUE in jmeter.properties file